# Embeddable headless browser for Java?

Tags: java, selenium, headless-browser

I'm developing a JavaFX desktop application which, as a part of its functionality, needs to headless render websites and be able to execute JavaScript against them.

Right now for this purpose I'm using JBrowserDriver, and while it works well, I found that for some sites it doesn't render the webpage as expected (frequently when the webpage is using modern CSS features such as flexbox), and sometimes I need to query some properties of the HTML elements, so for me it's important that it renders the website like a normal browser would do.

I know I can use Chrome or Firefox headless mode, but this would require a dependency on Chrome or Firefox on the computers my software will run, so I prefer a browser that I can bundle with my program, but I have been searching and at the moment I haven't found anything useful.

Are there any other good options?

Thank you.

Comment: One is Chromium Embedded Framework

Comment: [**PhantomJS**](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) or [**HtmlUnitDriver**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver)